# How to detect a cycle which doesn't consist of a particular node of the directed graph?

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Given a **directed graph**, which has n nodes( nodes are numbered 1 to n) and m **one-way** roads/edges between the nodes. We need to start the journey from node 1 and the destination is node n. We need to check if it is possible to travel infinitely on the roads without visiting the node n, if possible print "yes" or "no" otherwise. Also, if there is no path which exists from node 1 to n, print a "no". The value of n and m can be upto 10^5.

Example: n=5, m=5

1 2 [Here 1 2 means there exists an edge between node 1 and node2]

2 3

3 4

4 5

5 2

Answer: no, because we cannot traverse the nodes infintely without vising 5.

n=5 m=5

1 2

2 3

3 4

4 5

4 2

Answer: yes, there exists a path wherein we can travel without visiting node 5.

I have tried to implement the idea of Depth First Search first to check if there exists a path from 1 to n. If it exists then check if there is way to find a cycle in the graph which doesn't consists of node n. The idea is to customise DFS by initially making the nth node visited and then check for the cycle. The idea for cycle detection has been taken from the following URL - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/

My Approach

```
public static void dfsCustom(int source,int dest, int numberOfNodes)
    {
         boolean visited[]=new boolean[numberOfNodes+1];
         boolean recurVisit[]=new boolean[numberOfNodes+1];
         boolean res=customUtil(source,dest,visited,recurVisit);
         if(res)
           System.out.println("yes");
         else
         System.out.println("no");
    }
    public static boolean customUtil(int source, int dest, boolean visited[],boolean recurVisit[])
    {
         visited[dest]=true; //Making the destination node visited in the beginning.
         if(recurVisit[source])
            return true;
         if(visited[source])
           return false;
         visited[source]=true;
         recurVisit[source]=true;
         for(int v:graph[source])
         {
            if(customUtil(v,dest,visited,recurVisit))
              return true;
         }
         recurVisit[source]=false;
         return false;
    }
```

I have pasted my full code  here for checking the case - https://pastebin.com/CWwyTf1X

Is there some edge cases which it might not cover given the above constraints?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Have you considered just not including the paths that contains that node and see if there's a cycle in the remaining ones?

Comment: @Scratte, I have made the node n as visited initially and then tried to use simple depth-first search to find out a cycle. In my opinion making the nth node visited in the beginning itself is treating it non-existent for cycle detection

Comment: I see. In any case, since you seems to be asking a debug Question as "the code fails to pass the hidden test cases", you'll need to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't know what hidden test cases you are referring to. I suggest you make it as minimal as possible. Also, make the post sound less like a coding competition, as I suspect that is what set off the "homework" link.

Comment: @Scratte, thank you for your suggestion. I have now added my code snippet which basically shows my approach of making the destination node as visited in the beginning.

Comment: Asking a Question is harder than one would think. You'll need to address all the points made in the linked help page. No one can take the code you posted and run it and get the same result as you are, because you haven't included what you get, nor what you expect to get, nor how you're calling the code. Consider reading [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) as well.

Comment: Your post also still sounds like a competition Question. Note that once this post is closed, you should only make one (and final) edit to it. The first edit will push your post into the reopen queue where users will evaluate if the post should be reopened, but this will only happen once. What I'm trying to say is: Do not haste your edit. Take the time to make this post a superb one as a great Question in the repository of Questions that make up Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that the link to "minimal reproducible example" says "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself". I'm getting the feeling that you perhaps forgot to read it.

Comment: I have added a public link to my code which can help reproduce the problem and help in execution.

Comment: I noticed. But that means your Question is not self contained, meaning one need to go off-site to get all the information needed. That is the opposite of making sure all the information is included in the Question itself. I think you'll need to read about how to ask Questions here. The site is meant to be a collection of Question/Answers that are useful to a lot of users. Not just the one user that posts the Question.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you have a problem in this point:

```
   if(recurVisit[source])
        return true;
     if(recurVisit[source])
       return false;
```

maybe the second if was

```
 if (visited[source])
   return false;
```

Comment: Thank you @Rocco, I made the changes in the code in my post. That was a typo error while pasting it here.